# AudioBuffer.copyFromChannel returns empty Float32Array

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

AudioBuffer.copyFromChannel returns empty Float32Array from every channel of audiobuffer....is there any way to make this work correctly?

```
var floatarray1 = new Float32Array();
audioBuffer.copyFromChannel(floatarray1,0);
console.log(floatarray1)
```

[Output of "floatarray1" which returns empty Float32Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7tmb.png)

Answer (score 2):

`copyFromChannel()` will only copy as much data as possible. If the length of the given `Float32Array` is 0 it can not copy anything.

If you want to copy all the channel data you could do it like this:

```
const channelData = new Float32Array(audioBuffer.length);

audioBuffer.copyFromChannel(channelData, 0);
```